# Computer Stuck In Reboot Loop When Using Case Power Switch

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, hardware-failure

When I power my computer on using the Case power switch, the Motherboard returns code 20, then code 55, then power cycles again and again (displaying those same two codes).

However, if I press the power button directly on the Mobo, it boots normally and everything is fine.

Additional Detail: if I restart from windows, the computer also gets stuck in the power cycle loop.

Comment: A computer should only boot from the motherboard. What else do you want it to boot from?  That's like saying Airplane only gets into the air from the ground. And what do you mean by the power button directly on the motherboard(distinct from the 'case one'. Can you provide a picture?  Also, if you have issues with a switch attached to the motherboard then you can try tapping contacts together with a screwdriver.  So if there is an issue with the switch attached to the power pins, then you'd know.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue.  Have you confirmed the cable going from the cable to the motherboard is installed in the correct orientation?